# deploying angularjs app on Heroku: module angular not found

Tags: angularjs, heroku, deployment

I m trying to deploy my angularjs app on heroku.
I followed the steps given by heroku.
But when I m looking at the log I have this :

> /app/app/scripts/app.js:3 2014-03-05T11:05:09.262151+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   angular.module('angularuiprojectApp', [
>   2014-03-05T11:05:09.262151+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
>   2014-03-05T11:05:09.266533+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: angular
>   is not defined 2014-03-05T11:05:09.266533+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   Object. (/app/app/scripts/app.js:3:1)
>   2014-03-05T11:05:09.266533+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile
>   (module.js:456:26) 2014-03-05T11:05:09.266533+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>   2014-03-05T11:05:09.266533+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load
>   (module.js:356:32) 2014-03-05T11:05:09.266533+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>   2014-03-05T11:05:09.266533+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>   2014-03-05T11:05:09.266533+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup
>   (node.js:119:16) 2014-03-05T11:05:09.266533+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   node.js:902:3 2014-03-05T11:05:09.742460+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   /app/app/scripts/app.js:3

I don't understand why Heroku doesn't know about angular.

Here's the code of my app.js :

```
angular.module('angularuiprojectApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute','ui.bootstrap'
])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

My procfile content is :

> web: node app/scripts/app.js

If you have any idea...
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`app.js` is a file that configures AngularJS. It's not a web server like `express`. You need a web server to serve your Angular app. To do this create a new `web.js` file that starts a webserver serving your `app` or your `dist` directory.

You will need to install `express` and `gzippo` using npm to make this work.

Here is an example of `web.js` serving the `app` folder:

```
'use strict';

var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var express = require('express');
var nodeApp = express();

nodeApp.use(express.logger('dev'));
nodeApp.use(gzippo.staticGzip('' + __dirname + '/app'));
nodeApp.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

By the way, serving the `app` folder is not recommended, you should be serving the `dist` folder that is generated using the `grunt` command. Check out [this buildpack](https://github.com/nknj/heroku-buildpack-yo-angular) I wrote to deploy angular apps on heroku, it will handle everything for you if you are using grunt and bower to build your app.

Comment: great buildpack nknj! :)

Answer (score 2):

Heroku has a problem reading CDN's with `http` in the address. So in your project, remove `http` from all your CDN urls.

For example:

**If you have:**

```
<pre>http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></pre>
```

**Replace it with:**

`<pre>//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></pre>`

Answer (score 0):

I had a node.js app working fine locally, but the angular wouldn't work on Heroku. I had to change this line in my index.html for heroku to load angular. I replaced

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And it worked!

Update:
It looks like the issue is with the 'http:' part of the src, not the initial link. Not sure why heroku cannot handle the http there, but just get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the http part of the link, you allow the server to choose between http or https. This works for all CDN in general.

In general, I recommend this method ok link start with `//whatever.com` rather than `http://whatever.com`because you never know when links will change to https or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

while hosting your angular js web application on heroku, the problem comes up with the CDN. Heroku has a problem to read the CDN with **http**

**So, remove the http from your angular CDN**
and write it as

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>`